# Application freezes when changing windows keyboard input language

Tags: c#

When I run my application, do some work on it and click the language button on the Windows taskbar and change the input language, my C# application freezes displaying an hourglass cursor.  Does anyone have any idea on what may be going wrong? I have absolutely no clue where to start...

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED. Well, it's not a solution, but a workaround. The application works without any problems after changing a regional language setting in Windows XP. Open Start -> Settings -> Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options -> Languages -> Details ->Advanced and check "Extend support of advanced text services to all programs". I still don't know why there are problems when this option is turned off, but at least I have a workaround (not very comfortable, as I have to force all users to change that option in Windows XP).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your problem is hard to follow, since we don't know what is going on in your application. Neither we know which exactly code in your application freezes.

For others, the problem in your application is not clear. So having this quite weakly defined problem, it's hardly possible that someone can help.

You can do the following in order to resolve the issue:

1. Try to build a minimal test case, which reproduces the problem. Usually you'll need to start with a copy of your source code, and remove features until the bug is not reproducible any more.
2. After this, you will most likely see yourself, where the problem is.
3. If not, you can post the example and the changes which make the bug happen. Please kindly try to remove as much as possible from the example, leaving only essential part.

This way you will most likely have your problem solved.

Comment: Unfortunately the application is very big (it has been developed by 6 programmers for the last 3.5 years) and it is extremely difficult to carve out any independent bit for testing.  All simple applications just work without any problems.  I was hoping someone has seen a symptom like that before and could suggest a starting point for the investigation.

Comment: Doesn't your application consist of several units? Perhaps you can [try to] find the "offending" unit using your intuition and/or knowledge of the project structure.